# Unable to push UWP application to Microsoft Store flight

Tags: azure-devops, uwp

We haven't changed anything to our `store-publish@0` task, but pushing a flight to the Microsoft store now returns the following error:

```
Starting: Publish application to Microsoft Store (flight)
==============================================================================
Task         : Windows Store - Flight
Description  : Make a flight submission to the Windows Store
Version      : 0.2.28
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : 
==============================================================================
<redacted> exists true
Authenticating...
Authenticating with server...
(node:960) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:960) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
...
(node:960) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:960) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
Obtaining app information...
Obtaining flight resource for flight Internal in app <redacted>
Deleting existing flight submission...
Creating flight submission...
Submission https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/apps/<redacted>/submissions/<redacted> was created successfully
Deleting old packages...
Updating package delivery options...
Updating flight submission...
Creating zip file...
Uploading zip file...
##[error]Failed to upload file!

Error = Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: ingestionpackagesprod1.blob.core.windows.net. is not in the cert's altnames:
 DNS:*.blob.core.windows.net, DNS:*.bn7prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net,
 DNS:*.blob.storage.azure.net, DNS:*.z1.blob.storage.azure.net,
 DNS:*.z2.blob.storage.azure.net, DNS:*.z3.blob.storage.azure.net,
 DNS:*.z4.blob.storage.azure.net, DNS:*.z5.blob.storage.azure.net,
 ...
 DNS:*.z48.blob.storage.azure.net, DNS:*.z49.blob.storage.azure.net,
 DNS:*.z50.blob.storage.azure.net"
```

It looks I'm not alone, because I also found [this message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1413394/error-to-upload-zip-file-with-package-to-microsoft) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-dev-center-vsts-extension/issues/104).

Not exactly sure what's going on, because the hostname `ingestionpackagesprod1.blob.core.windows.net` has the following certificate that seems to be perfectly fine:

```
Common Name = *.blob.core.windows.net
Organization = Microsoft Corporation
City/Locality = Redmond
State/Province = WA
Country = US

Subject Alternative Names = *.blob.core.windows.net, *.bn7prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net,
 *.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z1.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z2.blob.storage.azure.net,
 *.z3.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z4.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z5.blob.storage.azure.net,
 *.z6.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z7.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z8.blob.storage.azure.net,
 *.z9.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z10.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z11.blob.storage.azure.net,
 ...
 *.z45.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z46.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z47.blob.storage.azure.net,
 *.z48.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z49.blob.storage.azure.net, *.z50.blob.storage.azure.net

Issuer = Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06
Serial Number = 3300CEC15364F00F12083E5647000000CEC153
SHA1 Thumbprint = CB18535B5D09EE66387C4AA3DDFB8675F0C11595
Key Length = 2048
Signature algorithm = SHA384-RSA
```

Comment: This issue is also tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-dev-center-vsts-extension/issues/104)

Comment: Your log shared comes from `store-flight@0` task not publish.  Checked there is no update on the task as no new commit [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-dev-center-vsts-extension/commits/master). Also the issue can be reproduced on Microsoft-Hosted agent. Mostly like a bug, it's also been reported in Developer community [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-to-upload-zip-file-with-package-to/10507419).